R function vector comprehension
It is surprising that I do not seem to able to find any source on this topic. How to do vector comprehension in R? That is, suppose that :
foo <- function(a,b,c){
    print(c(a,b,c))
}
x <- c(1,2,3)

Without altering the above code, how to replace :
foo(x[1],x[2],x[3])

by something better?
All the sources I have talks about list comprehension only and I do not want to convert numeric to list if unnecessary.

I thought this was a duplicate but I realise now that if you don't want to use do.call() then I closed it prematurely - I have reopened. Apologies. Can you explain more about what you're trying to do? I would just run do.call(foo, as.list(x)) here. I can't see any reason not to run as.list() with three values. How many parameters are you passing to your function? Are you doing this lots of times in a loop? It's helpful to explain the constraints otherwise it's hard to suggest alternatives. For example, you could use rlang::inject(foo(!!!x)) here - but does that solve the problem?

If you are calling foo many times you can write a proxy for foo calling do.call(foo, as.list(x)), like @SamR suggests.

I really think that do.call is the way to go here but if you insist on not converting x to a list then try this:
library(purrr)

Reduce(partial, init = foo, x)()
## [1] 1 2 3

functional::Curry would also work in place of partial.
Note
Inputs used
foo <- function(a, b, c) print(c(a, b, c))
x <- c(1, 2, 3)


I think you get points for creativity here but I'd really like to know what problem this solves.

@SamR, The question states "I do not want to convert numeric to list".

Yes - you've answered the question. What I mean is, what is the problem that the person asking the question is trying to solve. The only reasons I can think of for not type casting to list are either they're doing this operation many times in a tight loop and they don't want to call an extra function, or the vector is huge and they don't want to copy the values. I guess this may solve the second problem - I'm not sure - but I can't really imagine why a function would need to take thousands of parameters rather than a vector of values. I'm just wondering what problem they are trying to solve.
